# VLC - "Continue playback" never works

Tags: vlc-media-player

[Developer quote](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=124420#p418008):

> For resume playback to work on mac, all of the following conditions
>   need to be fullfilled. This is to avoid stupid questions to the user
>   (like if he wants to continue at position 2 seconds after start of
>   video, and similar).
>
> - File must be a local file on your hard disk. No stream or similar.
> - It must be longer than 3 minutes.
> - The position to save should be within the following range: starting at 5% of total playback time, stopping at 95%.

The same rules should apply to all operating systems. I have always used the latest version of VLC, currently 2.2.2.

Continue playback has never worked for me, the setting is enabled and I just reseted VLC preferences. The files are more than 3 minutes long, usually over 20 minutes. Video files are saved on my hard drive, but sometimes I use my secondary HDD (VLC is installed to SSD). I stop the playback in the 5%-95% range.
I've had this issue on Windows 8/10 and all Linux distros I've used.

Is there something I should try? How "resume playback" is supposed to work? Should the video position be always, automatically saved no matter  how I close VLC?

Answer (score 4):

Note that "save recently played items" setting has to be enabled in order for the feature to work.

[image: VLC 2.2.6]

[source](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=124420#p418262)

> [...]the playback position is stored together with a list of recent
>   file names and we cannot store them if the user does not want to keep
>   recent items at all. Note as well that the position is only stored for
>   the last (I think) 20 items or so.

---

In version 2.2.0 VLC couldn't resume playback for files started from operating system file explorer, but this appears to have been fixed in 2.2.1: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=123563#p421960

Comment: There may be differences between operating systems, as the developer states: "resume playback is implemented separately for both [Windows and OSX] (at the time).

Comment: This worked for me. I am wondering however why it was under "Privacy / Network Interaction" group?

Comment: @Alex The filenames are stored locally. VLC may save in plaintext, unlike mpv which uses some hash string or other not-human-readable identifier.